# Convert LESS to SASS from creative theme bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

I'm trying to convert LESS files from Creative Bootstrap Themes to SASS. It compiles with no error but the header brand class doesnt work as it should be. I inspect the class and find a warning "**invalid property value**" on following code:

```
color: fade(white, 70%);
```

here the converted code in SASS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) 
    background-color: transparent
    border-color: fade(white, 0.3)
    .navbar-header .navbar-brand 
        color: fade(white, 70%)
        &:hover,
        &:focus 
            color: white
```

and here the original in LESS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: fade(white, 30%);
    .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        color: fade(white, 70%);
        &:hover,
        &:focus {
            color: white;
        }
    }
```

Can someone give me some clue? Thanks

Comment: I don't believe an exact *fade* function exists in SASS as it does in LESS, you might want *lighten* depending on what you're trying to do: Here's a list of [Sass Functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html)

Comment: @vanburen I tried some function like _tint_ before but it doesn't work and _lighten_ is the missing link here. Thanks man.

Comment: @vanburen can you answer the question please. So I can close the thread. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the LESS **fade** function is causing the issue as it doesn't exist in SASS.  The **lighten** function appears to be an alternative depending on what you're trying to do: Here's a list of [Sass Functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is very old, but let me answer it to help anyone else that has this question. The `SASS` function that you are needing here is `transparentize`. The second parameter needs to be expressed as a fraction between 0 and 1 and must be the inverse of the `LESS` `fade` function. So, for your example ...

`fade(white, 30%)`

would become

`transparentize(white, 0.7)`

So this is the correctly converted `SASS`:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) 
    background-color: transparent
    border-color: transparentize(white, 0.7)
    .navbar-header .navbar-brand 
        color: transparentize(white, 0.3)
        &:hover,
        &:focus 
            color: white
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the alpha parameter of the `rgba` function did the trick for me.
For instance if in Less you have:

```
color: fade($color, 75%);
```

Sass would be:

```
color: rgba($color, 0.75);
```

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules#rgb